# One status table for all models?

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-key, table

lets say I have a users,posts and categories tables ..

- users table would have statuses like ( active, expired .. etc )
- posts table would have statuses like ( published, draft, archived .. etc )
- categories would also have different statuses

Is it bad if I did my tables like this:

users table:

```
- id
- name
- email
- password
- status_id
```

posts table:

```
- id
- title
- desc
- status_id
```

categories table:

```
- id
- title
- status_id
```

status table:

```
- id
- name ( active, expired , published, draft, archived .. etc )
```

Comment: Also consider using ENUM instead of a separate table.

Answer (score 0):

I would think so. Especially if you don't want the status `published` on users.. If you want to add a status to one, you're going to special case code for one of the consumers to exclude?

I would keep it simple -- two separate tables. Or if they're immutable (you won't be deleting and updating) status's and you're **only using them on the one table**, you can use an `ENUM` macro/check constraint.